# Replacing underscores with hyphens in .htaccess but stuck in a loop

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've followed various examples to use mod-rewrite to redirect from URLs containing underscores to URLs containing hyphens. But it gets stuck in a loop and I can't see what's wrong.

I want to redirect URLs like:

```
http://www.example.org/blog/archive/2016/12/31/my_post_slug_here.html
```

to:

```
http://www.example.org/blog/2016/12/31/my-post-slug-here/
```

All of that is simple enough except the underscores-to-hyphens. I currently have this in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/archives/([0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2})/([^_]*)_([^_]*_.*).html$ blog/archives/$1/$2-$3.html [N]
RewriteRule ^blog/archives/([0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2})/([^_]*)_([^_]*).html$ /blog/$1/$2-$3/ [R=301,L]
```

The second rule redirects correctly if I use a URL containing only a single underscore (e.g. `.../my-post-slug_here.html`). But the first - which should recursively replace underscores with hyphens until there's only one left - gets stuck in a loop. My log looks like:

```
[Mon Feb 20 14:35:47.430250 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 7844] mod_rewrite.c(476): 
[client 192.168.33.1:54128] 192.168.33.1 - - [www.example.dev/sid#7f6f3fcdecc8][rid#7f6f3fbb20a0/initial] 
[perdir /var/www/public/] applying pattern 
'^blog/archives/([0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2})/([^_]*)_([^_]*_.*).html$' to uri 
'blog/archives/2016/12/31/my-post-slug-here.html/archives/2016/12/31/my-post-slug-here.html/archives/2016/12/31/my-post-slug-here.html/archives/2016/12/31/my-post-slug-here.html/archives/2016/12/31/my-post-slug-here.html/archives/2016/12/31/my-post-slug-...
```

So it looks like it's replacing the underscores and then somehow getting stuck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules are almost correct. Issue is that Apache is appending original path info to rewritten URI and it is going into an infinite loop (due to flag `N` in place).

You need to add [`DPI` flag (Discard Path)](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/flags.html#flag_dpi) with `N` to stop this behavior.

After little bit of refactoring your rules can be:

```
# redirect when we have only one underscore in URI
RewriteRule ^blog/archives/(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2})/([^_]*)_([^_]*)\.html$ /blog/$1/$2-$3/ [R=301,NC,NE,L]

# otherwise keep replacing underscore with hyphen in a loop
RewriteRule ^(blog/archives/\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2})/([^_]*)_([^_]*_.*\.html)$ $1/$2-$3 [N,NC,DPI]
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much anubhava! It works first time! The examples I was trying to follow didn't have that but there must be something different here. Thanks for the refactoring too - a bit neater now :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this makes a difference, but maybe try making the rule's target absolute, by adding a `/` at the front:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/archives/([0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2})/([^_]*)_([^_]*_.*).html$ /blog/archives/$1/$2-$3.html [N]
```

Another thing you can maybe try is redirecting when there are no more underscores:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} blog/archives/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2)/[^\ \?]*_
RewriteRule ^blog/archives/([0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2})/([^_]+).html$ /blog/$1/$2/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^blog/archives/([0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2})/([^_]*)_(.*).html$ /blog/$1/$2-$3.html [L]
```

Comment: Thanks Jon - I'd tried the first idea, and that didn't work. anubhava's solution seems to do the trick.